# Implementing combinational lock in verilog

Tags: verilog, fsm

**Problem Statement**:

> Design and implement a control unit for a digital lock. The digital
> lock has the passcode “1010”. The code should be entered via 2 Push
> Buttons: one button for entering 1’s (B1) and another for entering 0’s
> (B0). Use a third push button (Reset) to add reset functionality.
> Based on the entered code, glow an LED for the following outputs
>
> 1. LED_0  will glow indicating PASS, if the entered 4-digit binary code is correct
> 2. LED_1  will glow indicating FAIL, if the entered 4-digit binary code is incorrect

We need to make sure output is given only after all four inputs are taken.

**Error**: My coded module won't ever show a pass or fail output.

[FSM State diagram to be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEFg2.jpg)

```
module lock_FSM(
    input B0,
    input B1,
    input Reset,
    input Clk,
    output reg PASS,
    output reg FAIL
    );
    reg [3:0] present_state, next_state;
    parameter S0 = 4'b0000, S1 = 4'b0001, S2 = 4'b0010, S3 = 4'b0011, S4 = 4'b0100;
    parameter E1 = 4'b0101, E2 = 4'b0110, E3 = 4'b0111, E4 = 4'b1000;
    
    //State register
    always @(posedge Clk, posedge Reset)
    begin    
    if(Reset == 1)
        present_state = S0;     
    end

    always @(posedge B0, posedge B1)
    begin
        present_state = next_state;
    end
    
    //Input block
    always @ (present_state, B0, B1)
    begin
    if(B0 == 0 && B1 == 0)
    next_state = present_state;
    else
    case (present_state)
    S0 : next_state = B1 ? S1 : E1;
    S1 : next_state = B0 ? S2 : E2;
    S2 : next_state = B1 ? S3 : E3;
    S3 : next_state = B0 ? S4 : E4;
    E1 : next_state = E2;
    E2 : next_state = E3;
    E3 : next_state = E4;    
    endcase
    end
    
    //Output
    always@(present_state)
    begin
    case(present_state)
    S4: begin PASS = 1; FAIL = 0; end
    E4: begin PASS = 0; FAIL = 1; end
    default : begin PASS = 0; FAIL = 0; end
    endcase
    end
endmodule
```

[image: Test wave form is as such:]

The output should have been PASS = 1 after 4th posedge in (B0 or B1) and stayed there until Reset is pressed.

I need to update the states only when one of B0 or B1 is pressed (as B1 and B0 are push buttons).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how you coded your state register.  All assignments to a signal should be made within a single `always` block, not from 2 blocks.  Change:

```
always @(posedge Clk, posedge Reset)
begin    
if(Reset == 1)
    present_state = S0;     
end

always @(posedge B0, posedge B1)
begin
    present_state = next_state;
end
```

to:

```
always @(posedge Clk, posedge Reset) begin    
    if (Reset == 1) begin
        present_state <= S0;     
    end else begin        
        present_state <= next_state;
    end
end
```

In a typical FSM, updating the present state should be unconditional (not dependent upon signals like `B0`).  You should account for those conditions in your `next_state` logic. Also, good coding practices recommend nonblocking (`<=`) assignments in sequential `always` blocks.

Another issue is that you have no way to exit the `E4` state (aside from an asynchronous reset).  Perhaps you should add a case to your `case` statement for that.  Also, since you declared only 9 of the possible 16 states, the convention is to use a `default` statement to handle the undefined states.